# How to call a method multiple times in parallel using CompletableFuture in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a web service in Spring Boot which needs to make requests to an external web service to retrieve live rates for multiple currency pairs.

The method that makes the external API call currently looks like this;

```
@Async
    public CompletableFuture<Double> getBaseRateForCurrencyPair(String sourceCurrency, String targetCurrency) {
        String key = sourceCurrency.toUpperCase() + targetCurrency.toUpperCase();

        Double baseRate = 0.00;

            String baseRateProviderUrl = "https://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=" + currencyLayerAccessKey + "&source=" + sourceCurrency + "&currencies=" + targetCurrency;
            HttpClientRequest clientRequest = new HttpClientRequest(baseRateProviderUrl);

            try {
                Response response = clientRequest.get();
                String responseStr = response.body().string();

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
                baseRate = AppHelper.round(jsonObject.getJSONObject("quotes").getDouble(key), 2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(baseRate);
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is call this method an unknown number of times depending on how many currency pairs we need to get rates for, wait for all of them to complete and store the results ready to be returned in an API response.

I have a method that receives a source currency code, and a list of destination currency rates.

```
public RateResponse getLiveRates(String sourceCurrency, String[] targetCurrencies) {
        RateResponse rateResponse = new RateResponse();

        rateResponse.setSourceCurrency(sourceCurrency);

        /* Loop through target currencies and start a thread for each */
        Map<String, CompletableFuture<Double>> ratesMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (String targetCurrency : targetCurrencies) {
            ratesMap.put(targetCurrency, matrixHelper.getBaseRateForCurrencyPair(sourceCurrency, targetCurrency));
        }

        /* At this point, I would loop through the Map and grab the results, but only when all are finished */

        return rateResponse;
    }
```

My issue is, I can't figure out how to wait until all async calls are finished before I start looping through the Map and retrieving the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `CompletableFuture` method `allOf(CompletableFuture<?>... cfs)`? Look for docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-)

Comment: I looked at that, but all example I see show passing across a known number of CompletableFutures, where as in my case I have an unknown number of them.

Comment: Method accepts varagrs which in turn is an array. So you can transform Map values to array and execute the method.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution might look like this:

- store the created `Future` objects in some *global* set/list
- to then loop and wait on the entries of that set, *before* doing anything else

So, your first snippet changes to:

```
CompletableFuture rv = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(baseRate);
thatGlobalList.append(rv);
return rv;
```

And then:

```
availableFutures = 0;
while (availableFutures < thatGlobalList.size()) {
  availableFutures=0;
  for (CompletableFuture future : thatGlobalList) { 
    if (future.isDone()) {
      availableFutures++;
    }
```

Of course, when your *map* is already built for you, and contains all the future objects, then simply iterate over the **values** of the map, and sure, all of them are giving you `isDone()`!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe I am missing something here, but if you iterate all completables and call their [CompletableFuture#get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--) then by definition you will finish the iteration when **all** futures have completed.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're using `CompletableFuture`, your `getBaseRateForCurrencyPair` method returns only after all the processing is done.
To do all that in parallel, you'll have to use something like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<Double> getBaseRateForCurrencyPair(String sourceCurrency, String targetCurrency) {
    CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture 
  = new CompletableFuture<>();
    Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
        String key = sourceCurrency.toUpperCase() + targetCurrency.toUpperCase();

        Double baseRate = 0.00;

        String baseRateProviderUrl = "https://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=" + currencyLayerAccessKey + "&source=" + sourceCurrency + "&currencies=" + targetCurrency;
        HttpClientRequest clientRequest = new HttpClientRequest(baseRateProviderUrl);

        try {
            Response response = clientRequest.get();
            String responseStr = response.body().string();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
            baseRate = AppHelper.round(jsonObject.getJSONObject("quotes").getDouble(key), 2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        completableFuture.complete(baseRate);
        return null;
     });


    return completableFuture;
}
```

And to wait for all the tasks to be done, you can use something like this:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(ratesMap.values().stream().toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new))
```

The you can just iterate the map and use `mapValue.get()` to get the `Double` value.

Comment: I tried that, but my IDE flags up the error 'Generic array creation'?

Comment: @SheppardDigital Use just `CompletableFuture[]::new` instead of `CompletableFuture<Double>[]::new`